# Pygame KEYDOWN not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a rectangle move up and down on the screen. But when I press the keys to make it go up or down I have to continuously press it each time to make it move. The way I interpreted `pygame.KEYDOWN` was that I can hold down the desired key and the rectangle would move until I release the key.

Code for key pressed:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # all keys
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        # quit game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        # check key down presses
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # left paddle
            if keys[pygame.K_q]:
                left.move(-30)
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                left.move(30)

            # right paddle
            if keys[pygame.K_p]:
                right.move(-30)
            if keys[pygame.K_l]:
                right.move(30)

        # user let up on a key
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == keys[pygame.K_q] or event.key == keys[pygame.K_a]:
                left.move(0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_p or event.key == pygame.K_l:
                right.move(0)

    # call animation function
    draw()

    # FPS
    clock.tick(120)
```

The `left` and `right` objects are coming from the following class:

```
import pygame


class Paddle:

    def __init__(self, screen, h, w, left):
        self.screen = screen
        self.width = w
        self.y = h / 2
        self.pad_width = 10
        self.pad_height = 70

        if left:
            self.x = self.pad_width / 2
        else:
            self.x = self.width - self.pad_width * 1.5

    def show(self):
        WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
        rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.pad_width, self.pad_height)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, WHITE, rect)

    def move(self, speed):
        self.y += speed
```

Comment: `KEYDOWN` detects the key *going* down not *being* down. You should be detecting `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` and keeping track of each keys current state (hint, use `event.key` in all cases instead of `keys`)

Comment: @NickA I changed the events to `if event.key == pygame.K_q:` etc. but I still need to press the key every time to make it move.

Comment: you need to keep the current key state `q_down=True/False` depending on if it was just pressed/released, then in your game loop you can do `if q_down: left.move(-30)` ( note i say in your game loop, not the event handling loop)

Comment: @NickA gotcha, thanks. Seems to work

Comment: I'll write a proper full answer when I have access to a computer rather than my phone until then I'll write a brief one just now

Comment: @NickA perfect thanks! If not I'll post an answer and try my best to re-explain what you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game loop should comprise of three main steps:

1. Handling user input
2. Updating the game state
3. Re-rendering your scene

I think by doing steps 1 and 2 together you may have confused yourself a bit.

Firstly, `KEYDOWN` detects a key *being pressed*, rather than *being down*. Because of this I suggest keeping track of current key states, as a basic example:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
        q_down = True
else:
    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
        q_down = False
```

Now user input is handled you can simply use:

```
if q_down: left.move(-30)
```

in your game loop to update the game state (note this should be outside your event loop).

---

I also suggest your read [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/how-should-i-write-a-main-game-loop) from game dev SE and have a look at the linked resources to better understand the game loop.